# WETH() in IUniswapV2Router01

Tags: uniswap

The WETH() function is returning WMATIC address on mumbai testnet, I want to change it to the address of WETH used in mumbai by aave. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The point of WETH() in uniswapV2Router is to return the address of the wrapped version of the chains native token. If you need WETH address somewhere in your code just hardcode it.

Edit : i'm assuming you're building on top of uniswapV2Router. If you're forking it and you want to change what WETH returns ehh.. dont. It'll break all the functions that are supposed to send MATIC to the user (removeLiquidityETH, swapExactTokensForETH...)